# Control multiple product prices with a single price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I am customising wooCommerce so the prices are $0.00 on a second order for specific products. I achieved it with the code below.

If I multiple products from that category, there is a $100 charge for the orders from product. I want to limit it to $100.

The use case would be:
Each product is of $100.

First time order: Customer selects multiple or a single product > charged $100.

Second time order: Customer selects multiple or a single product > charged $0.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'conditionally_change_cart_items_prices', 10, 1 );
function conditionally_change_cart_items_prices( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;
    // Set HERE the Products to check in this array
    $targeted_product_ids = array( 1107, 1113, 1115, 1116, 1117, 1118, 1119, 1121, 1122, 1123 );
    $products_bought = array();

    // Set Here your custom price (1st purshase)
    $custom_price1 = 100; // First purshase
    // Set Here your custom price (more purshases than first)
    $custom_price2 = 0; // Next purshases

    // Detecting if customer has already bought our targeted products
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){
        $customer      = wp_get_current_user();
        $customer_id   = $customer->ID; // customer ID
        $customer_email = $customer->email; // customer email

        // Checking each product in the array
        foreach( $targeted_product_ids as $product_id ){
            if( wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $customer_id, $product_id) ){
                // We set all (targeted) purchased products in an array
                $products_purchased[] = $product_id;
            }
        }
    }
    // Checking cart items and changing item prices if needed
    foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // When a targeted products already purchased is in cart we set price 2
        if ( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $products_purchased ) ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $custom_price2 );
        } 
        // When a targeted products is in cart and has not been purchased we set price 1
        elseif ( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $targeted_product_ids ) ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $custom_price1 );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what issues you are getting with your current code..?

Comment: If I select 5 products from the specific category, there is a $100 charge for all products in cart. I want to limit it to $100 instead of $500